# Default Image Viewer for Application Images

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-image

My Question is I will show some of the images from sd card using the below link

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/

user will select a particular image which will show the selected image using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
                        "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Now once the user swipes it will go to other images present in sd card but i want to show the images from my application, means i want to show the images of app in the default image viewer.also when once user selects a image it will shows the list of apps to open the image is there any way to eliminate this and shows the image in default image viewer and once swipes go to next image present in the app not from the sd card